# How to use only use .pluck to grab the first x amount of records?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, pluck

Can `.pluck` be used to get say only the first 5 values

e.g.

```
 CategoryItemKey.where(category_id: @category.id).pluck(:name)
```

I only want the first 5 names. Also if there are only 3 names it wont throw an error it will just grab 3.

Cant see it in the docs or from a google search. How would I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CategoryItemKey.where(category_id: @category.id).pluck(:name)[0...5]`

Comment: Wow it was so simple haha

Comment: You should possibly also include a `.limit(5)` in your query. In case CategoryItemKey is a large table, this would fetch all entries and then discard all except the first five, leading to some overhead.

Comment: @panmari can I just replace [0...5] with `.limit(5)`? Saving on overhead is the only reason i'm doing it.

Comment: You can leave it if you need 5 entries, even if there are less available.